# what kind of insect is this

Tags: entomology

It has what appears to be antennas in both front and back and legs front and back orange coloured dots ob front and rear of a blackish brown body[image]

Comment: This isn't one insect, it's a mating pair; I'm pretty sure they're flies, but can't go further than that on the evidence at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Those are two mating "love bugs". Flies (Diptera) in the family Bibionidae. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovebug